# java, how to change Unicode characters to normal characters?

Tags: java, android, unicode

I have a WordPress based weblog.
I have installed [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) plugin, in order to get my response in JSON format.
I'm developing application for Android and I want to show content of my weblog inside my Android application.
I'm using following libraries in order to parse JSON

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I'm sending request to server to get content of a page of my weblog. But, I have no idea why my server sends contents of page in Unicode format. My logs are showing this output:

```
02-23 21:16:21.148: D/ContentDownloader(3536): Try to open: http://www.kamalan.com/?feed=json&paged=1
02-23 21:16:23.243: D/Fragment_TopicsList(3536): Server Response: [{"id":1784,"title":"\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0622\u0645\u0648\u0632\u0634\u06cc &#8211; \u0641\u0635\u0644 \u06cc\u0627\u0632\u062f\u0647\u0645 \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a API","permalink":"http:\/\/www.kamalan.com\/?p=1784","content":"<p align=\"justify\"><img class=\"alignright size-full wp-image-1785\" style=\"margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;\" alt=\"don't panic\" src=\"http:\/\/www.kamalan.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/02\/01.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"113\" \/>\r\n\u062a\u0639\u062f\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u0648\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0631 \u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0646\u062a \u0647\u0627 \u0648 \u0627\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u0644 \u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a API \u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u062f\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646\u062f. \u062a\u0639\u062f\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u062f\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646\u062f \u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u06af\u0631 \u062f\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0628\u06cc\u0633 \u062e\u0627\u0631\u062c \u0627\u0632 \u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0648 \u0633\u0645\u062a \u0633\u0631\u0648\u0631 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u062f \u0686\u0637\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u06cc\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0631\u0627 \u0645\u0633\u062a\u0642\u06cc\u0645 \u0628\u0647 \u0622\u0646 \u0648\u0635\u0644 \u06a9\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u062f\u0631 \u0622\u0646 \u06a9\u0648\u0626\u0631\u06cc \u0632\u062f. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0622\u0645\u0648\u0632\u0634\u06cc \u067e\u0627\u0633\u062e\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a \u0628\u0647 \u0633\u0626\u0648\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0639\u0632\u06cc\u0632\u0627\u0646.<\/p>\r\n<p align=\"justify\"><span id=\"more-1784\"><\/span><\/p>\r\n<p align=\"justify\">\u0631\u0648\u0634 \u062f\u0631\u0633\u062a \u062f\u0633\u062a\u0631\u0633\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u0631\u06cc\u0645\u0648\u062a \u062f\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0628\u06cc\u0633 \u062f\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0647\u0627 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u062c\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u062a\u0635\u0627\u0644 \u0645\u0633\u062a\u0642\u06cc\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u062f\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0628\u06cc\u0633 \u06cc\u06a9\u0633\u0631\u06cc API \u0633\u0645\u062a \u0633\u0631\u0648\u0631 \u0646\u0648\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0634\u0648\u062f \u0648 \u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u062f\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0634 \u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u0637\u0631\u06cc\u0642 API \u0628\u0647 \u0633\u0631\u0648\u0631 \u0627\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u06a9\u0646\u062f\u060c \u0633\u0631\u0648\u0631 \u0639\u0645\u0644\u06cc\u0627\u062a \u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645 \u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0646\u062c\u0627\u0645 \u062f\u0647\u062f (\u062f\u0631 \u062f\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0628\u06cc\u0633 \u06a9\u0648\u0626\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0632\u0646\u062f\u060c \u0631\u06a9\u0648\u0631\u062f\u06cc \u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0636\u0627\u0641\u0647\u060c \u0622\u067e\u062f\u06cc\u062a \u06cc\u0627 \u067e\u0627\u06a9 \u06a9\u0646\u062f) \u0648 \u0646\u062a\u06cc\u062c\u0647 \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u062f. \u0628\u062f\u06cc\u0646 \u062a\u0631\u062a\u06cc\u0628 \u0627\u0628\u0633\u062a\u0631\u06a9\u0634\u0646 \u0647\u0645 \u0628\u062e\u0648\u0628\u06cc \u0627\u0646\u062c\u0627\u0645 \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0648\u062f.<\/p>\r\n<p align=\"justify\">\u0632\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u06cc\u0633\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 PHP \u0627\u0633\u062a \u0686\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u0648\u0644\u0627\u064b \u0645\u062c\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u062f\u0648\u0645 \u0627\u06cc\u064
```

When I'm opening above URL in my browser I see the result in this format as well.
How can I change Unicode format to normal format?
Is there something wrong with settings of my WordPress? (I'm not familiar with PHP but I found [String Repertoire](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-repertoire.html). Is it related to my problem?)

Comment: What is "normal format" for you?

Comment: Parse it using a JSON parser, which will decode characters for you.

Comment: I see a mix of tags and `unicode as string` content. Certainly, there is some conversion gone wrong on the server side.

Comment: @ Cort3z, I think ASCII but I'm not sure. that's why I said normal characters.

Comment: @  JB Nizet, Actually I'm doing it after getting server response. but since characters are in Unicode format, parser cannot parse it :(

Comment: JSON-simple parses that without any problem. Which JSON parser do you use? Where's the code? Also, pasting the response of the feed URL into JSONLint shows that the JSON is valid.

Comment: @Hesam: which JSON parser do you use? If it can#t handle those unicode escapes, then it's not conformant. How does "can not parse it" look like? Do you get an exception? Unexpected output? I strongly suspect that the JSON parser handles it just fine, but some later step in your processing doesn't display the arabic characters correctly and that leads you to think it's a prasing problem.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure in your case but paste it into ipython.
store Unicodes in a variable and then print it. It might work